# Cannot create new project in Firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

While I creating project in the Firebase console, I getting the error "You have exceeded the maximum number of free Google projects that you can create. Try deleting unused projects in the Google APIs console or request a project limit increase".

I removed unused projects from Firebase console, now i have only 2 projects in Firebase console, still it showing the error.

Is there any limit for project creation in Firebase?

Comment: The projects are pending deletion. It takes a week before they actually are permanently deleted.

Comment: Thanks Frank for your information. Is there any limitation for how many project i can creat in firebase console?

Comment: There's no limit on the number of projects in general, but there is a limit on the number of projects on an unpaid plan. The exact limit for that varies, from what I understand.

Comment: For unpaid plans, there is the FAQ on why and how to request more projects: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6330231?hl=en

Answer (score 4):

Firebase Projects are tied to a Google Cloud Service Project. Deleting the firebase project won't automatically delete the Google Cloud Service Project. If you want to delete the other unused Google Cloud Service projects then navigate to https://console.cloud.google.com. There it will allow you to delete the Google Cloud Service Projects. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a limitation due to the number of Google cloud platform projects of your account.
Normally, you can create about 10 projects, if you want to create more, a pop-up comes and you can apply for more projects through the pop-up link.

Comment: Is it free to exceed the limit or should I pay?

Comment: no，you should delete project from gcp console or apply for more projects though Google form

Comment: Do you know how much time it will take to get an approval from Google?

Comment: It depends on their workload, maybe several days, If you write more details, it will be faster.