# Error prompting to increase project limit while creating new project in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-console, google-developers-console

While trying to add a new project in Firebase, it's showing the warning as:

```
You've reached the project limit for your account.
You can add Firebase to an existing project or request an increased limit.

                                                   Request an increase // button
```

Later I checked in Google Developer Console and deleted all existing projects in there. Still this issue persists and I am not able to create a new project in Firebase. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase maximum projects and apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485736/firebase-maximum-projects-and-apps)

Comment: Also see [the comments by Frank (Firebase engineer) on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120044/cannot-create-new-project-in-firebase-console#comment63682529_38120044) - it can take ~1 week for deleted projects to actually be removed from the system.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses...This really helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is likely answered on the [Firebase maximum projects and apps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41485736/2754146) question, the most important parts are from [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103)'s (a Firebase engineer) comments on the [Cannot create new project in Firebase console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38120044/2754146) question:

> The projects are pending deletion. It takes a week before they actually are permanently deleted.
>
> There's no limit on the number of projects in general, but there is a limit on the number of projects on an unpaid plan. The exact limit for that varies, from what I understand.

Furthermore, the [Cloud Platform Console Help section](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6330231) explains why these limits are in place:

> **Why are there limits to how many projects I can create?**
>
> Quotas protect the Google Cloud Community from unforeseen spikes in usage. However, as your usage of Google Cloud Platform increases, you can request an increase in your quota.